# Return to fragment after taking a picture

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

I had 3 fragments A,B and C

**A-->B-->C**

I open the camera from fragment **C** to take a picture, when I take it, I click on OK to store it, so it returns to the beginning fragment **A** like the application was closed, So what to do to stay in my fragment **C** which I open the camera  ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        String root = Utils.getFirstWritableDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(root+"/.XXXX_IMAGES");

                        if(!myDir.exists())
                            myDir.mkdirs();
                        File file = new File(myDir+File.separator + time+".jpg");
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, XX);
```

Comment: how you take pic in fragment C? by intent or custom camera view?

Comment: by intent, you can see my code.

Comment: Did you `add` or `replace` fragments when switching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the camera using an `Intent` creates and brings that camera's `Activity` in front of yours, therefore triggering the `onPause()` method. `onStop()` may also be called if the `Activity` is being killed to reclaim memory.

Depending on how you changed the view between your fragments A, B and C, their state may be lost upon `onStop()`, causing your application to reset to fragment A, *i.e.* the default one.

To work around that you must implement state saving and restoring by overriding `onRestoreInstanceState()` and `onSaveInstanceState()`, respectively (or, depending on how persistent you want fragments to be, `onCreate()`/`onStop()`), restoring the C fragment if it indeed was the last one.

Your `Activity`'s `onActivityResult()` will be called after `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: I passed state using onSaveInstanceState from fragment to Activity, then on Activity I call onRestoreInstanceState, it works now !